# BeautifulSoup, 1 element have 2x same links, how to print only 1?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, findall

**Hi,
after i run this code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get('https://coinpaprika.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

coin_list = soup.find('tbody')
coin_list_items = coin_list.find_all('a')

for coin_name in coin_list_items:
    names = coin_name.string
    links = 'https://coinpaprika.com' + coin_name.get('href')
    print(names)
    print(links)
```

**Program print:**

```
None
https://coinpaprika.com/coin/btc-bitcoin/
Bitcoin
https://coinpaprika.com/coin/btc-bitcoin/
None
https://coinpaprika.com/coin/xrp-xrp/
XRP
https://coinpaprika.com/coin/xrp-xrp/
None
https://coinpaprika.com/coin/eth-ethereum/
Ethereum
https://coinpaprika.com/coin/eth-ethereum/
```

**Instead of:**

```
Bitcoin
https://coinpaprika.com/coin/btc-bitcoin/
XRP
https://coinpaprika.com/coin/xrp-xrp/
Ethereum
https://coinpaprika.com/coin/eth-ethereum/
```

**I understand that reason of that is:**

```
<td class="table__fixed-cell">
                    <a href="/coin/btc-bitcoin/"><span class="coin-icon currency_images-0"></span></a>
                </td>


<td class="table__fixed-cell">
                    <a href="/coin/btc-bitcoin/">Bitcoin</a>
                    <small>BTC</small>
                </td>
```

**But still I don't know how to print only the second one.** 
**Anyone can help me with that?**

Comment: So, if `names is None`, you don't want to print the link, right?

Comment: I want program to print:

Bitcoin
https://coinpaprika.com/coin/btc-bitcoin/
XRP
https://coinpaprika.com/coin/xrp-xrp/
Ethereum
https://coinpaprika.com/coin/eth-ethereum/

Answer (score 1):

some links has empty anchor text because it used for icon image,

```
<a href="/coin/btc-bitcoin/"><span class="coin-icon currency_images-0"></span></a>
```

add check

```
for coin_name in coin_list_items:
    names = coin_name.string
    if not names:
      continue
    links = 'https://coinpaprika.com' + coin_name.get('href')
    print(names)
    print(links)
```

Comment: Can't believe that i was so easy, thank you so much :)

Comment: you're welcome, please consider mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just find the tag which contains text.

```
coin_list_items = coin_list.find_all('a',text=True)
```